# Fixing range of y values for graph with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have written the following code to display a basic line graph.

```
Sub addchart()

    If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Delete
    End If
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ch As chart
    Dim dt As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    
    i = Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set dt = Range(Cells(2, 14), Cells(i, 14))
    Set ch = ws.Shapes.AddChart2(Width:=1300, Height:=300, Left:=Range("a13").Left, Top:=Range("a13").Top).chart
    
    With ch
        .SetSourceData Source:=dt
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Deflection Curve"
        .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
        
End With
End Sub
```

But the trouble with this is that the range of Y axis adjusts itself according to the data automatically. I want to fix this range so that the change in the graph is noticeable.

For example, the following two graphs vary in the range of values they cover but they look basically the same because the y axis is adjusting itself. One goes from 0 to -9 and the other from 0 to -25. If I can fix the range to say 0 to -30, the difference in the two graphs would be more apparent.

[image: graph1]

[image: graph2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
With ch.Axes(xlValue)
    .Minimumscale = -30
    .Maximumscale = 0
End with
```

Relevant links:

- [Chart.Axes method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.axes)
- [Axis Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.axis(object))

Comment: Thanks! Had to move the values around a little but I got the point.

Comment: Glad it worked! Please mark it as an accepted answer so the question shows as solved for the rest of the SO community.

Comment: I tried but there was a timer on it for some reason. Have done so now. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Spencer, the following code gets the result I want

```
Sub addchart()

    If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Delete
    End If
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ch As chart
    Dim dt As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    
    i = Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set dt = Range(Cells(2, 14), Cells(i, 14))
    Set ch = ws.Shapes.AddChart2(Width:=1300, Height:=300, Left:=Range("a13").Left, Top:=Range("a13").Top).chart
    
    With ch
        .SetSourceData Source:=dt
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Deflection Curve"
        .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    End With

    With ch.Axes(xlValue)                  'fixing range of values

    .MinimumScale = -30
    .MaximumScale = 0

    End With
End Sub
```